# Nav bar links not working

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, navbar, bootstrap-4

I am making a website using bootstrap. I have made a nav bar where I want the menu items to link to the different sites. However it is not working at all - it is usually never a problem getting links to work, but I am new in using Bootstrap and i feel like I'm missing something - do you need to have a js code to get your links to work? Normally I just write something like  I have put all the sites in the same folder and I have tried so many things now. I have also tried giving the items and ID and then adding a js code, but nothing happens.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#aboutus').on('click', function() {
    location.href = "About kopi.html";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container-fluid">

  <nav class="row navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Name</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="About kopi.html" id="aboutus">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included the Bootstrap files (CSS and JS) and jQuery in your source?

Comment: is any error in the console or in css check the pointer-event:none present or not

Comment: Yes if you mean the:                                                                              
<script src="bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>                                           
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bs/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: @Maria Please see how I made a [mcve] from your post

Comment: If you really need to do stuff in JS when you click, you may want to stop the link  `$('#aboutus').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); location = $(this).prop("href") });`

Comment: I think you should avoid name spacing your html files. About kopi.html should probably be About-kopi.html. You don't need necessary need javascript to navigate to other pages. A simple <a> element with a valid href should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Hi Maria and welcome to Stack Overflow.

The syntax for your `a` tag is correct. And thus it should work.

Saying that your link doesn't work, is extremely vague. What you could try:

- Make sure all your styles and scripts from Bootstrap are loaded. (This includes dependencies such as jQuery and Popper.js)
- Make sure the pages you're referring actually exist. (Does this file: `Portfolio.html` exist?)

Comment: yes the Portfolio page and the index (home page) does exist, but the other ones are not yet made.. I thought I'v make the portfolio link to the index html first. And sorry what I meant was that when I click on my menu items (in this case the portfolio) it does not link to the page I requested. And it is normally not a problem, but this bootstrap is new to me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using some classes that are specific to Bootstrap 4 in your markup, but including the Bootstrap 3 JS and CSS.

Try using the Bootstrap 4 files instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

Here's a fiddle I created to try to reproduce your problem. It seems to work with the Bootstrap 4 files:

https://jsfiddle.net/bbz0t198/